# Type of column of PostgreSQL in Jhipster

Tags: java, postgresql, jhipster

I'm using jhipster to generate an entity of a table. The table has two columns with types: timestamp without time zone and numeric. Which is the suitable type to choose in jhipster? I tried to search on google but it no help. I found to Instant for timestamp but don't know if it work with "timestamp without time zone ", and should I use Integer or Long for "numeric"?

Answer (score 0):

`timestamp` is short for `timestamp without time zone` so that might be ok though I believe Instant's should be in UTC and I do not know if your timestamp's are UTC or your local timezone if the latter then LocalDateTime would be a better fit.

Numeric is a decimal floating point type so integer types are not a good fit. Java has BigDecimal which would be a good fit.